# Slowly Draw A Line In Android

Tags: android

I have a Line class composed of two Points of two ints each that I draw with a wrapper over Canvas.drawLine().

Easy so far.

I *want* to have that Line drawn slowly from one Point to the other. My best guess is to make a function that will dice up my Line into an list of Lines, starting from the first Point with each subsequent Line getting longer and longer till it reaches from one Point to the other. Then, I will have a Canvas.drawLine wrapper that will take that array of Lines, and iterate over them, drawing each one with a pause of some sort in between them, giving the appearance of the line "growing".

Is there something in the android libraries that already does this and/or would this be better solved some other way?

**Edit: This is android 2.1**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android has libraries for creating animations. Look into [tweened animations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) and the [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) class.

Comment: Any hints on the best way to implement this? If I am calling canvas.drawLine(1, 1, 10, 10, paint), how could I change that to be a tweened animation so it slowly grows from (1, 1) to (10, 10)? I didn't see from the documentation what function would best do this, maybe scale animation?.

Comment: It looks like I could get an image to grow like that, but this is a dynamically generated line with a dynamic orientation, and it would be a big pain to try to make an image, then rotate it, then grow it, so I would prefer something simpler if it exists.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html. If you are using 3.0 or higher, property animation may do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can have one line with a fixed starting point and on each draw the end point increments . I believe this approach has better performance .